# SQL Server will not restart after moving tempdb

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm building a SQL Server on AWS. Everything works fine until I try to move the tempdev and templog from the default locations to separate disks. From SSMS I execute the script (see below), but the SQLServer service won't restart and SSMS will no longer connect. I've tried it several times (terminated the instance and spun up a new one) with the same result. Seems like this should be simple -- what could I be doing wrong?

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE TempDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = tempdev, FILENAME = 'd:\datatempdb.mdf')
GO
ALTER DATABASE TempDB MODIFY FILE (NAME = templog, FILENAME = 'e:\datatemplog.ldf')
GO
```

Comment: Make sure the account SQL Server is running under has read/write access to the path you specified.

Comment: Confirmed: read/write access is NOT the problem.